# How to scale a value entered in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

If I enter `123456`, it should be displayed as `1.23456`. However, the value stored internally should still be `123456`.

Is this possible in Excel? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

right click the cell and go to format, then down to custom format and enter:
`0"."00000`

This will change the display format with a "decimal" after the first digit, but it won't change the value of the contents of the cell (as seen in the formula bar)

Comment: +1. Thanks. Is it also possible to display only 2 digits after the '.'? Like `1.23`?

Comment: you want to have a custom display and trim the number in the same cell as the original number? No, I don't think that's possible. I can do that in a new column though, but not with the original data.